# Convert multiples line bash script to single line

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, bash, shell

I am trying to write a bash script to use in python code.

***Multi-line bash command*** (this works perfectly when run directly from terminal)

```
mydatefile="/var/tmp/date"
while IFS= read line
do
    echo $line
        sh /opt/setup/Script/EPS.sh $(echo $line) | grep "WORD" | awk -F ',' '{print $6}'
    sleep 1
done <"$mydatefile"
```

***My single line conversion***

```
mydatefile="/var/tmp/date;" while IFS= read line do echo $line; sh /opt/setup/Script/EPS.sh $(echo $line) | grep "WORD" | awk -F ',' '{print $6}'; sleep 1; done <"$mydatefile";
```

***ERROR***

```
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `done'
```

Comment: When doing such a transformation, just replace every newline in the multiline script by a semicolon. Both (linefeed and `;`) are statement separators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Missing a `;` (fatal syntax error):

```
while IFS= read line; do echo ...
#                   ^
#                 here
```

More in depth :

- combined `grep+awk` in a single command

```
mydatefile="/var/tmp/date"
while IFS= read line; do
    echo "$line"
    sh /opt/setup/Script/EPS.sh "$line" | 
        awk -F ',' '/WORD/{print $6}'
    sleep 1
done < "$mydatefile"
```

- use more quotes ! 
  Learn how to quote properly in shell, it's very important :

  > "Double quote" every literal that contains spaces/metacharacters and *every* expansion: `"$var"`, `"$(command "$var")"`, `"${array[@]}"`, `"a & b"`. Use `'single quotes'` for code or literal `$'s: 'Costs $5 US'`, `ssh host 'echo "$HOSTNAME"'`. See
  >   http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes
  >   http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Arguments
  >   http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/words
- finally:

```
mydatefile="/var/tmp/date;" while IFS= read line; do echo $line; sh /opt/setup/Script/EPS.sh "$line" | awk -F ',' '/WORD/{print $6}'; sleep 1; done < "$mydatefile";
```

Comment: Also, the first semicolon should not be in quotes: `mydatefile="/var/tmp/date;" while` should be `mydatefile="/var/tmp/date"; while`. And BTW those unquoted variable references (`$line` instead of `"$line"`) are suspicious, and what's the point of `$(echo $line)` instead of just `"$line"`?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this conversion might be to paste the script onto the command-line, then look up in the history - though this might depend on the version of command-line editor you have. Note that you do need a semicolon before `do`, but NOT after. You are punished for too many semicolons as well as too few.

Another way would be to line-by-line fold each line in your script and keep testing it.

The binary chop approach is do the first half, test and undo or continue.

Once you have it down to 1 line that works you can pasted it into python.